# Question modified by Community-trace of edits?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/185074/how-to-know-if-a-network-is-locked-by-mac-address) says - that it has been modified by Community *X* mins ago.
[image]
But when I went through the question, it was last edited 21st Aug 2011.  I checked all the answers also to see if any of the answers were modified. But they were not.
So how does this work?
*Note: I know that Community is not a real person*

Comment: I wonder what happens when a Low Quality answer gets deleted as a result of getting the necessary number of "Recommend Deletion" votes from the VLQ queue?  Does an answer *have* to be deleted by a person with Delete privileges, or can it be done by consensus?  If an answer is deleted because seven people voted to delete it, I hope the last person (the one who cast the vote that broke the camel's back) doesn't get "credit" for the deletion.  And, finally — does the deletion of an answer register as a modification to the question?

Comment: @Scott: The voting in the LQ Posts queue doesn't delete anything.  Sufficient "recommendations for deletion" get it into a queue where 20K+ rep users vote on deletion.

Comment: @fixer1234: OK, that's interesting, but I'm not sure it affects my point.  If a post gets deleted by vote of 20K+ users in the Delete Queue, does it get labeled as being deleted by Community?  And, if that happens to an answer, does it cause the question to be marked as modified by Community?  even though there's no evidence of modification that can be seen by <10K users?

Comment: [This image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fNBnk.png) demonstrates that it is possible for a post to be deleted by Community.  In this instance, it was a question that was deleted, and I don't know the mechanism (i.e., was this the result of a vote of 20K+ users?), but it is possible.